# Android Notification type on Pebble watch

Tags: java, android, notifications, pebble-watch

I'm writing application for Android (let's say SMS application) and I would love to have a message icon on my watch when app popups `Notification`.

I'm not able to do this - always end up with "ring bell" icon on Pebble watch.

I even tried to use `Notification` categories on `Notification`:

```
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setContentTitle("some text")
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify);
```

Tried all categories - always only ring bell icon is shown.
After asking Pebble this question their support went silent...

Icon:

[image: Ring bell icon]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've got some information from Pebble forum (my own post):

> Assuming you are registering for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER` then we need to whitelist the app before we will process notifications from it. We’ll whitelist apps if you can assure us it produces good notifications (i.e. has stacking + actions).
>   Alternatively you can check the “Disable built-in SMS notifications” preference.

Answer by "Orviwan" from Team Pebble.

Source: https://forums.pebble.com/t/android-setting-notification-type-icon-type-shown-on-watch/23937/3

So, basically if you are registering for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER` and this still does not work you have to write to Pebble team.